# ASP.NET render View content based on what is passed in to the ActionResult method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a theoretical question regarding rendering a single View with different content based on what is passed in using MVC in the .NET framework.

Basically I want to have a single page called "Create Template", but depending on what is clicked on in the page prior - say "New template" or "New template from existing" button which will dictate what content CreateTemplate View will have.

I could have multiple views CreateTemplate and CreateTemplateFromExisting but I feel that is bad practice to do such a thing.

Can someone provide me some code or pseudocode on how I would develop such a thing? I assume we pass in some sort of value to the view then use javascript/jquery to render the page with a PartialView according to this particular value.

Any assistance with helping me build a better understanding would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can define and set viewbag.template in controller action and Pass it to view page then set layout based on viewbag.write below code in controller.

```
ViewBag.Template="Your Template Name";
```

and you can access to it in view page.

```
@{
var myTemplate=ViewBag.Template;
Layout=myTemplate;
}
```

ofcourse, you must write complate path of template page.

Comment: Yes something like that. Can you provide me some sample code on this? Would I pass an ID of some sort via viewbag, then in the view say if the viewbag ID ==1 generate this otherwise generate this. Is this the sort of logic to use? 

Also would have all the content on the page and just show and hide it based on this ID with jQuery?

Comment: if use asp.net mvc else you don't need to jquery for this case.